# Draw the maginitude as function of frequency

Tags: transistors, transfer-function

The circuit is this one, it consists of two common emitter transistors

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7Frz0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Some of the components where given but the others I had to find out by myself.

The next step was to find the transfer function for AC for \$\frac{U_{C1}}{U_1}\$ and \$  \frac{U_{C2}}{U_1}\$, with \$r_{be}=2 k\Omega.\$
And I got the following expression,
 $$\frac{U_{C1}}{U_1}=\ \frac{\beta R_{C1}}{r_{be}}$$
 $$\frac{U_{C2}}{U_1}=\frac{\beta^2 R_{C1} R_{C2}}{2 r_{be}}$$

**This is where I am confused and need some help**

I have to draw the magnitude of \$\frac{U_{C1}}{U_1}\$ and \$  \frac{U_{C2}}{U_1}\$, and in the solution it is supposed to look like this

[image: Bell-curved plot of the magnitudes of the transfer functions]

This is the result, but I just don't know how it came to be like that, so I would really appreciate some help, since it took me a lot of time to make this question.

Comment: Could you clarify how come \$ \frac{U_{C1}}{U_1}=\ \frac{\beta R_{C1}}{r_{be}} \$ and \$ \frac{U_{C2}}{U_1}=\frac{\beta^2R_{C1}R_{C2}}{2r_{be}}\$ (they both have a gain independent of the frequency) and still you would expect a bell-shaped plot? My suggestion is that you double check the expressions you got for \$  \frac{U_{C1}}{U_1}\$ and \$  \frac{U_{C2}}{U_1} \$

Comment: @jDAQ, I drew the equivalent circuit for ac and then found it out. I asked a professor about this and I was told it is right. But not sure why the plot is like that

Answer (score 3):

> This is where I am confused

You are not the only one. First off you haven't defined U1, Uc1 and Uc2. I presume they are the input signal voltage. signal voltage at T1 Collector, and signal voltage at T2 Collector.

Your formula assumes that both stages have the same input impedance and same current gain, even though the bias currents are different. This *could* be true if the transistors had just the right different characteristics, but for the general case when they don't the formula would be clearer if the two stage gains were grouped separately, like this:-

$$ \frac {Uc2}{U1} = \frac{\beta1 * Rc1}{Rbe1} * \frac{\beta2 * Rc2}{Rbe2}$$

However this formula is not complete, because it ignores the loading effect that the  second stage has on the output of the first stage. Assuming that C2's impedance is negligible, Rbe2 is effectively in parallel with Rc1, so the actual gain of the first stage (when driving the second stage) is:-

$$ \frac {Uc1}{U1} = \frac{\beta1 * (Rc1 || Rbe2)}{Rbe1}$$ where || is the [parallel operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_(operator)).

(Even this isn't quite correct, but Rb2 is high enough compared to Rbe2 that it can be ignored)

> This is the result but I just don't know how it came to be like that

Your graph looks like a crude attempt to plot the frequency response of each stage. I'm guessing your question is why does the amplitude drop at low and high frequencies?

At the low frequency end the signal amplitude reduces because capacitive reactance \$ Xc = \frac{1}{2\pi fc}\$, so as frequency reduces more signal voltage is dropped across C1 and C2, creating [high pass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-pass_filter) RC filters. This starts to have significant effect at the 'cutoff' or 'corner' frequency \$\frac{1}{2\pi RC}\$, below which the level drops off at a rate of -20 dB per decade.

For the first stage this frequency is easily calculated using the values of C1 and Rbe1. 1 / (2π * 80 nF * 2k) = ~995 Hz. For the second stage we must also take into account Rc1. Again the effective resistance here is Rc1 || Rbe2. 4k Ω || 2k Ω = ~1.33k Ω. 1 / (2π * 3.3 uF * 1.33k Ω) = ~36 Hz.

Since the first stage's 'pole' has a much higher frequency than the second stage, this will dominate the loss at low frequencies and Uc2 will roll off at ~20 dB per decade.

At the high frequency end the internal [parasitic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parasitic_capacitance) capacitances of the transistors, in combination with the resistances, form [low pass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-pass_filter) RC filters. Each stage produces one pole, but the second stage has no load capacitance so its cutoff frequency will be higher and the first stage will dominate, making the level drop off at ~20 dB per decade at high frequencies too.

Since we don't have values for the parasitic capacitances we cannot calculate the upper corner frequency. To get some idea of what to expect I simulated your circuit in [LTspice](https://www.analog.com/en/design-center/design-tools-and-calculators/ltspice-simulator.html) using 2N3904 transistors. Here is the result:-

[image]

Comment: thank you very much. Could I ask another question that is part of this exercise ?

Comment: Sure. Post it as a new question with a link to this one.

Comment: this is a maybe simple question regarding plotting the impedance   [Link to question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/480580/plotting-impedance-of-an-inductor-and-capacitor-in-series)

Answer (score 0):

Well, we have the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvaI3G.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When analyzing a transistor we need to use the following [relations](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/transistor/tran_2.html):

- $$\text{I}_\text{e}=\text{I}_\text{b}+\text{I}_\text{c}\tag1$$
- Transistor gain \$\beta\$:
  $$\beta=\frac{\text{I}_\text{c}}{\text{I}_\text{b}}\tag2$$

Using the following Mathematica code:

```
FullSimplify[
 Solve[{β1 == Ic1/Ib1, β2 == Ic2/Ib2, Ie1 == Ib1 + Ic1, 
   Ie2 == Ib2 + Ic2, V1 == Vbe1, V4 == Vbe2, Ib1 == I2 + Ix, 
   Ix == Ie1 + I1, I3 == Ic1 + I4, I6 == I2 + I3, I7 == I5 + I6, 
   Ib2 == I4 + I5, Iy == I7 + Ic2, Ie2 == I1 + Iy, Ix == (Vx - V1)/R1,
    I2 == (Vy - V1)/R2, I3 == (Vy - V3)/R3, I4 == (V3 - V4)/R4, 
   I5 == (Vy - V4)/R5, Ic2 == (Vy - V5)/R6}, {Ix, Iy, Ic1, Ic2, Ie1, 
   Ie2, Ib1, Ib2, I2, I3, I4, I5, I6, I7, I1, V1, V3, V4, V5}]]
```

And using your gives values, we get the following code:

```
FullSimplify[
 Solve[{100 == Ic1/Ib1, 100 == Ic2/Ib2, Ie1 == Ib1 + Ic1, 
   Ie2 == Ib2 + Ic2, V1 == (7/10)/s, V4 == (7/10)/s, Ib1 == I2 + Ix, 
   Ix == Ie1 + I1, I3 == Ic1 + I4, I6 == I2 + I3, I7 == I5 + I6, 
   Ib2 == I4 + I5, Iy == I7 + Ic2, Ie2 == I1 + Iy, 
   Ix == ((1/s) - V1)/(1/(s*80*10^(-9))), 
   I2 == ((12/s) - V1)/((113/100)*10^6), I3 == ((12/s) - V3)/4000, 
   I4 == (V3 - V4)/(1/(s*(33/10)*10^(-6))), 
   I5 == ((12/s) - V4)/565000, Ic2 == ((12/s) - V5)/2000}, {Ix, Iy, 
   Ic1, Ic2, Ie1, Ie2, Ib1, Ib2, I2, I3, I4, I5, I6, I7, I1, V1, V3, 
   V4, V5}]]
```

Solving that, gives:

```
{{Ix -> 3/125000000, 
  Iy -> (3 (505000 + 412581 s - 528 s^2))/(200000 s (2500 + 33 s)), 
  Ic1 -> 3/1250000 + 1/(1000 s), 
  Ic2 -> (-12 + 100/s + 331125/(2500 + 33 s))/50000, 
  Ie1 -> (101 (1250 + 3 s))/(125000000 s), 
  Ie2 -> (101 (250000 + 99 (3075 - 4 s) s))/(5000000 s (2500 + 33 s)),
   Ib1 -> (1250 + 3 s)/(125000000 s), 
  Ib2 -> (250000 + 99 (3075 - 4 s) s)/(5000000 s (2500 + 33 s)), 
  I2 -> 1/(100000 s), I3 -> (40/s + 2649/(2500 + 33 s))/40000, 
  I4 -> -((33 (-9125 + 12 s))/(5000000 (2500 + 33 s))), 
  I5 -> 1/(50000 s), 
  I6 -> (505000 + 19911 s)/(200000 s (2500 + 33 s)), 
  I7 -> (515000 + 20043 s)/(200000 s (2500 + 33 s)), 
  I1 -> -((2525 + 6 s)/(2500000 s)), V1 -> 7/(10 s), 
  V3 -> 8/s - 2649/(25000 + 330 s), V4 -> 7/(10 s), 
  V5 -> 12/25 + 8/s - 13245/(2500 + 33 s)}}
```

So, we get:

$$\text{V}_3-\text{V}_4=\frac{18250 - 24 \text{s}}{2500 \text{s} + 33 \text{s}^2}\tag3$$

Using \$\text{s}=\omega\text{j}\$, we get for the magnitude:

$$\left|\text{V}_3-\text{V}_4\right|=\frac{2}{\omega}\sqrt{\frac{83265625 + 144 \omega^2}{6250000 + 1089 \omega^2}}\tag4$$